# CakePHP: fetch related records in order?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-model

I have two models: `Event` and `Match`. An event can have many matches. My `Match` model has `$order = array('match_order' => 'asc')`. The `match_order` column in my `matches` database table is just a simple `INT` column to order matches.

I have a controller method that updates the order of matches. However, because I fetch matches through the event, they don't seem to come in ascending by `match_order`, but by the `id` column. Here is an example call:

```
<?php
class EventsController extends AppController {
    public function view($id) {
        $event = $this->Event->find('first', array(
            'conditions' => array(
                'Event.id' => $id
            ),
            'contain' => array('Match')
        ));
    }
}
```

All the related matches come back as expected, but just not in the right order. I've cleared my model caches, is there anything else I need to do to get the matches order by the value in the `Match` model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it. Forgot I could specify `order` in my model associations, so I've added the following to my `Event` model:

```
<?php
class Event extends AppModel {
    public $hasMany = array(
        'Match' => array(
            'order' => array(
                'match_order' => 'asc'
            )
        )
    );
}
```

Comment: You can also specify the order in your find query, simply add an "order" key to the options array specifying the desired order.